# Sum rows at specific column intervals

Tags: r, rowsum

I have a large data frame of 1129 rows and 4662 columns. I want to sum the row values in a data frame at intervals of every 3 columns, and then return 1 for each of these sums if the row sum every 3 columns was >0, or return 0 if the sum<1. I have added a small reproducible example below. I would like to sum the row values of column 1 to column 3, and then the row values from column 4 to column 8 (and so on in my real data).

```
df <- read.table(text ="     2005-09-23_2005-09-26  2005-09-27_2005-10-30  2005-10-07_2005-10-08  2005-10-09_2005-10-10  2005-10-11_2005-10-12  2005-10-13_2005-10-14
1  1       0     1     1     1     1           
2  1       1     0     0     0     0     
3  NA      NA    NA     NA     NA     0", header = TRUE)
```

The result I am after would be this:

```
result <- read.table(text ="     2005-09-23_2005-10-08  2005-10-09_2005-10-14
1  1       1           
2  1       0     
3  NA      0", header = TRUE)
```

I looked for similar questions and it seems that rollapply ([R: summing over an interval of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607166/r-summing-over-an-interval-of-rows)) OR rowsum could work ([R: summing over an interval of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607166/r-summing-over-an-interval-of-rows)), but I can't find a way to sum rows using columns as intervals instead of rows, nor how to do it in a repetitive sequence. Would someone be so kind to help me with some code for doing this? Thank you very much!

Comment: I need more clarity - (a) *"sum the row values.. at intervals of every 7 columns"* do you mean sum columns 1 to 7, columns 8 to 14, etc? Or do you mean sum column 1 + 8 + 15 + ..., columns 2 + 9 + 16 +...? (b) *"and then return 1 for each of these sums if the row sum every 3 columns was >0 or 0 if this sum<1.*" Where does `3` come from? Is this a typo and is supposed to be `7`? If the sum is `0.5`, it is both >0 and <1, so what should the answer be? (c) Your example data has less than 7 columns, not sure how to proceed...

Comment: Hi Gregor, sorry for not being clear, I have edited my question. So I would like to sum the row values from columns 1 to 3, then row values from columns 4 to 6, and then row values from columns 7 to 9, etc. Pretty much I need to have my data clumped or aggregated every 3 columns, which in my real data represent days...that is aggregate the data as explained above in intervals of three days. I hope this helped clarify.

Answer (score 1):

This works only if the number of columns is divisible by the interval.

```
+(sapply(split.default(df,unlist(lapply(1:(ncol(df)/3),rep,3))),rowSums) > 0)
   1  2
1  1  1
2  1  0
3 NA NA
```

maybe someone else can find a more elegant way of creating the split other than 
 `unlist(lapply(1:(ncol(df)/3),rep,3))`

Comment: Rather than `split`ting, you could use `apply` with most any of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15265512/903061)... not sure that it would be any more elegant in the end. Something like `apply(df, 1, function(x) colSums(matrix(x, nrow = 3))) > 0`, but then you'd need to manipulate the output to get it in the right format...